# I want to use my iOS application Project inside iOS SDK Framework project. or copy the resources and files of this project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk, storyboard

I have designed and developed iOS mobile application project, I want to use this project inside my iOS Framework SDK project as a sub project or sub module of the SDK Framework project, Need to understand this it is not a application project in which I want to use this, that one is iOS SDK Project.

Comment: kindly note this if I copy the View then outlets are connected with original project I want to remove there reference with original project and create it with my project where I pasted the layout.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.